# Get words from first line until first space and without first character in python

Tags: python

I have a textfile where I want to extract the first word, but without the first character and put it into a list. Is there a way in python to do this without using regex? 
A text example of what I have looks like:

```
#blabla sjhdiod jszncoied
```

Where I want the first word in this case blabla without the #.
If regex is the only choice, then how will the regex look like?

Comment: have you tried anything? If so  put it here

Comment: Insufficient problem description: how many leading number sign should be filtered out? Do you consider any non-space as continuing the word or which special characters terminate it? Is only the first line of the file interesting?

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
l = []
for line in open('file'):
    l.append(line.split()[0][1:])
```

Edit: If you have empty lines, this will throw an error. You will have to check for empty lines. Here is a possible solution:

```
l = []
for line in open('file'):
    if line.strip():
        l.append(line.split()[0][1:])
```

Answer (score 1):

Pythonic way:

```
my_list = [line.split(' ', 1)[0][1:] for line in open('file') if line.startswith('#')]
```

Answer (score 0):

> a **textfile** where I want to extract the **first word**, but without the
>   **first character** and put it **into a list**

```
result = []
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    l = next(f).strip()    # getting the 1st line
    result.append(l[1:l.find(' ')])
print(result)
```

The output:

```
['blabla']
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple enough if your input is so regular:

```
s = "#blabla sjhdiod jszncoied"
s.split()[0].strip('#')
blabla
```

`split` splits on whitespace by default. Take the first token and strip away `'#'`.

Comment: if input is "##blabla sjhdiod jszncoied", your output will blabla!

Comment: @DRPK And why would that be wrong? The OP states "without the #"... it is not clear what the intended behaviour is in your case.

Comment: plz read question agian! OP said : A text example ...!!! example, Where I want the first word in this case blabla without the #.!!! in this case!! in this sample!!

Comment: @DRPK In this case(!!) in this sample(!!), my solution produces the desired output. Your criticism is entirely based on some other data example that you have made up along with the desired output for your made up example. How do you know for sure that "the #" in "without the #" is singular?

Comment: and how do you know??!!!! you do not sure! this is not a general answer for OP question, ask op about this discussion and if he say i just have this type of data, i will vote up you!

Comment: OP wants to remove first character of each line and extract first word. you should write a global answer for this question just like others in this page!